# Inputting amount of zoom manually

Tags: 3d-view, interface

Is is possible to input the amount of zoom manually in Blender, instead of using the <kbd>Mouse Scroll</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Mouse Scroll</kbd>, as that does not seem measurable?

Comment: I don't think so, the only "measurable" way is to use ctrl + and ctrl - to make discrete zoom jumps...

Answer (score 1):

A convenient way to do this doesn't seem to be available. But you can lock the camera to the view and then change the camera's position.

- Press <kbd>Num0</kbd> to view the scene from the active camera
- (optional) Press <kbd>Home</kbd> to maximize the camera region in the viewport
- In the 3D View's properties shelf select *View* > **Lock Camera to View**

[image: locking camera to view]

Zooming with the mouse does not change the camera's focal length but its position. You should be able manually change the “zoom level” by scaling the camera towards / from the object that you're looking at.

As far as I can tell the camera scale is not considered for the values of *Depth of Field*, but as a precaution one can enable transformation lock for the scale value of the camera.

[image: transformation lock]